# How to output to the source data file?

Tags: alteryx

I am brand new to Alteryx and am building a workflow that will be reused with several different Excel reports. Each report has a different format (different column headers, etc).

Before running the workflow, I change the **Data Input** and update the fields in the **Select Tool**.

At the end of the workflow, I need to output the results to a new sheet within the original Excel workbook.

I know that the **Input Tool** has the "*Output File Name as Field*" option, but I can not figure out how to use that within the **Output Tool**.

Is there a better way to do this? Right now, I am having to select the new file in the **Input Tool** and the **Output Tool** on each run; if I forget to change the output, it will overwrite the sheet in the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose a field to determine the file that will be output.
In the **Output Data tool**, check "Take File/Table Name from Field" and select "Change Entire File Path". You then choose which field contains the output file name. Does that help with your problem?